# listview inside a tab android

Tags: android, listview, tabs

I

I am working on a listview. I have a tab with 4 elements. When I click on tab2 I want to display a listview. The problem is that I just see the first element from the list in my activity. If I test the application separatly (display the list with the elments) everything is ok.

Need help. Thank you!

Main.java

```
public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_menu);

        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

        // Android tab
        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, SLS_v1Activity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Key")
        //  .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_android_config))
            .setIndicator("Key")
            .setContent(intentAndroid);
....

//      / /add all tabs 
        tabHost.addTab(tabKey);
        .....
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

}
```

In the new activity I have the tab_contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set fill_parent:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
</ListView>
```

Comment: i did set fill_parrent and the issue is the same. In the new activity I can just see the first element from the list:)